# How to open photo from Photo hub with 3rd party apps using edit link in Silverlight 8.1 app

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Prior to Windows Phone 8.1 version we have abilty to open picture from picture hub using App Connect from Picture Hub (apps... link when open specific picture in picture viewer).

How to open picture from 3rd party app in WP 8.1 Silverlight app?

I upgrade project to Silverlight 8.1 but I don't get my app in a list with edit options.

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

In order to register for Edit picker, your app needs to declare the following extension in WMAppManifest

```
<Extension ExtensionName="Photos_Extra_Image_Editor" 
           ConsumerID="{5B04B775-356B-4AA0-AAF8-6491FFEA5632}" 
           TaskID="_default" />
```

More info can be found [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662932%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Igore, that is true for WP 8.0 but for WP 8.1 Silverlight app, it doesn't work at all. See this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/8aba9b05-aa38-44ce-b84f-c0c25c19174f/wp-81-how-to-open-photo-from-photo-hub-with-3rd-party-apps?forum=wpdevelop

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar but not exactly the same problem. I made an app for wp8 silverlight. The app appeared in the edit list for photos or images.
When I upgraded the project to wp81 my app appeared in the edit list but it wasn't called. It just happend nothing.

I found this comment on social.msdn.microoft.com:
"After updating to the new developer preview (8.10.14147.180) this problem is gone on my phone. It is of course still there in my emulator since it isn't updated (8.10.12358.1191). So the question now is when I can release the WP8.1 specific version of my app, since this functionality is a rather central part of it..."
and I can confirm this. 
On my emulator it does not work (OS Version 8.10.12358.1191) but on my device (OS Version 8.10.14147.180) it works.